# Listing file names from an old commit

Tags: git

I have deleted several files from the repository a long time ago.  Now years later I want to look at them.  If I know the names of one of those files, I can look at the history for one of them using:

```
git log -- path/to/file
```

If I want to see a version of that file from an old commit, I use this:

```
git show COMMIT:path/to/file
```

But all of this assumes I know the path/to/file, which I don't.  Is there a way to list all the files that existed at the time, from a given COMMIT?

I realize I can repeatedly do this until I find it:

```
git checkout -- COMMIT
```

But a complete file list from an old COMMIT would be ideal.  Does such a capability exist?  Given the comprehensiveness of git, I'll bet there is, but I surely don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all commits that deleted files like:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --oneline
```

- `--diff-filter=D` selects only files that are deleted
- `--name-only` shows the filenames
- `--oneline` uses a one-line commit description

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all files at a given commit use `git ls-tree -r $COMMITID`